# When adding a tab with the "+" in firefox, why does it open yahoo, instead of my homepage?

Tags: windows-7, firefox

I am running Windows 7 Home Premium SP1. When firefox is running, and I click the "+" to add a tab, firefox launches yahoo in the new tab, instead of my home page. How do I correct this?

Here is a screenshot of the situation:

[image: firefox new tab issu]
Firefox version is listed in this screenshot:

[image: Firefox version]

**Answer**

The *New Tab Homepage* extension had stopped working. I disabled it and then used both answers below as two concurrent steps. I used [SearchReset](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/searchreset/) @MrMAG linked in his answer, then used `about:config` that @AthomSfere recommended to reconfigure the new tab homepage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In firefox, in the Address bar type `about:config`

Search for newtab:

[image]

Double click that option, and change it to your requested home page for a new tab.

Comment: I changed the browser.newtab.url but it still opens yahoo. specifically: http://search.yahoo.com/?fr=freeze&type=W3i_NA,167,3_6,Tab%20Search,00000000,0,0,0,0

Comment: Once I disabled an extension called New Tab Homepage, this worked.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the [SearchReset](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/searchreset) extension to reset some preferences to the default values.

**Note:**
*This add-on is very simple: on installation, it backs up and then resets your search preferences and home page to their default values, and then uninstalls itself. **(it won't show on the "Firefox > Add-ons" page (about:addons))**

This affects the search bar, URL bar searches, and the home page.*

Comment: I did this, which did exactly what it was supposed to, but noticed that I needed to  do some maintenance with the add-ons. I disabled the New-Tab homepage extension, and then changed the newtab.url back to what I wanted it to be. I'm up voting both answers, because they were both steps in the process that worked. Thanks.